# Get certain div by Id using html dom

Tags: php, dom, domdocument

i am trying to get the content of certain div using html dom

here is my code

```
<?php

    $event_id = $_GET['eventId'];

    //Get the url
    $url = "static/section35.html";
    $html = file_get_contents($url);
    $doc = new DOMDocument(); // create DOMDocument
    libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
    $doc->loadHTML($html); // load HTML you can add $html
    if($html) {
    $divs = $doc->getElementById('e' .$event_id);

    $elements = $doc->getElementsByTagName('tbody');

    $toRemove = array();

    // gather a list of tbodys to remove
    foreach($elements as $el)
      if((strpos($el->nodeValue, 'desktop') !== false) && !in_array($el->parentNode, $toRemove, true))
        $toRemove[] = $el->parentNode;    

            foreach($elements as $el)
      if((strpos($el->nodeValue, 'Recommended') !== false) && !in_array($el->parentNode, $toRemove, true))
        $toRemove[] = $el->parentNode;  

    // remove them
    foreach($toRemove as $tbody)
      $tbody->parentNode->removeChild($tbody);

    echo str_replace(array('style="display: none;','</h3><table','http://www.drakulastream.eu'),array('', '<table',''),$doc->saveHTML());
}
  else {
        echo "<center><h3 style='color:#003366;'>There are no events today</h3></center>";
           }
?>
```

the html structure from which i want to get div is like this :

```
<div id="event-pane" class="class1">
   <div id="e170923" class="class2">
   <div id="e170948" class="class2">
   <div id="e170923" class="class2">
```

i want to get the div whose id is e170923 this div is included within the div event-pane

i have made many trials with my code above but not working and i get nothing 
so what is wrong with this

Comment: You want to do it using php or JavaScript

Comment: @Shivam Shah offcourse php, but do u have other idea

Comment: Document.getElementById(<?php echo $_GET['eventid']; ?>):

Comment: @ShivamShah not working

Comment: Your question is not clear. Please reduce the code in the question to the bare minimum case the reproduces and shows your issue. Do not copy over code from your existing programming, write the example new from scratch explicitly looking for demonstrating the issue. That should clarify anything pretty quickly.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this

```
$url = "static/section35.html";
$html = file_get_contents($url);
$dom = new DOMDocument("1.0", "utf-8");
$dom->loadHTMLFile($html);
$div = $dom->getElementById('e170923');

echo $div->textContent;
```

Comment: you did it simply but its not the case here e then 170923 which is $event_id and how to deal with the other functions in my code in the question

Comment: @mirandakerry what will be the event_id and why you are using same id 170923 for two divs ?

Comment: two div with same id is just example and not real, $event_id will be the numbers after e

Comment: @mirandakerry what will be the $even_id then ? where you are getting stuck ?

Comment: $event_id will be the numbers after e like in e123456 $event_id=123456

Comment: @mirandakerry Then Im not finding any issues, once again you verify $even_id are getting correctly. Sorry